# Is there a simpler form of $x^{\ln x}$ than $e^{(\ln x)^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> I am trying to find the value of $x^{\ln x}$.

My attempt

Let $y=\ln x$.

Then $e^y=x$.

Then $x^{\ln x}=(e^{y})^{\ln x}=(e^y)^y=e^{y^2}=e^{(\ln x)^2}$

Can we simplify this further?
The main problem is to find the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^{ln n}}$
so I was trying to find a simple form of it

Comment: Yes, that is right, but I wouldn't say it is any simpler to write $x^{\ln x}$ as $e^{(\ln x)^2}$. I think $x^{\ln x}$ is already the simplest form, and there's not much you can do. Note that $e^{(\ln x)^2}$ is not the same thing as $e^{\ln(x^2)}$, which *can* be simplified.

Comment: Try $x^{\ln(x)}=e^{-i\cdot i\ln^2(x)}=\cos(-i \ln^2(x))+i\sin(-i \ln^2(x))$ which can represent the $x<0$ part of the function. There is a way to separate the real and imaginary parts without the $i$ in the argument, but that makes it complicated.

Comment: For $n > e^2$ one will have $\ln n > \ln (e^2) = 2$ and hence $\frac{1}{n^{\ln n}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all such $n$. Does this help?

Comment: This is an example of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Just use the hint by leslie townes.